# Using reduce to sum array of p5.Vector objects

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

The following code throws an error in the line with reduce:

```
let vectors

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400,400);
    vectors = [];
    vectors.push(createVector(100,100));
    vectors.push(createVector(100,0));
    vectors.push(createVector(0,100));
    let s = vectors.reduce(p5.Vector.add, createVector(0,0));//error!
    console.log(s.x,s.y);
}

function draw() {
    vectors.forEach(v => line(0,0,v.x,v.y));
}
```

The error seems to occur in the p5.js code for the vector `add` method. The error message begins:

`p5.js says: There's an error as "set" could not be called as a function (on line 91666 in p5.js [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@vv1.4.0/lib/p5.js:91666:22]).`

What seems most baffling about this error is that the code works without error if the offending line is replaced by:

```
let s = vectors.reduce((u,v) => p5.Vector.add(u,v), createVector(0,0));
```

This is sufficient for my intended application, but I would like to understand the error rather than just find a kludgy way to sidestep it. My question is thus -- why does the attempt to use reduce directly with `p5.Vector.add` fail but wrapping it in an anonymous function succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [`p5.Vector.Add`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/add) can take in a third optional argument:

`p5.Vector.add(v1, v2, [target])`

In that example it defines target as such:

> p5.Vector: the vector to receive the result (Optional)

In your original version you are passing arguments from the reduce function into `p5.Vector.Add`. However, the third argument for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#parameters) is `currentIndex`, an integer.